# GitVersion using descriptors and auto increment version number for trunk based development

Tags: tfs, nuget, semantic-versioning, gitversion

I am implementing a CI process on TFS. I would like to use semantic versioning and semantic versioning should be incremented automatically. Also, I would like to use descriptors like “CI”, “beta”, and “release”.

It seems GitVersion is a suitable tool for this purpose. But as far as understood, especially descriptors generated according to git branch. We don't use gitflow, we use trunk based development.

[versioning nuget package](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2016/05/26/versioning-nuget-packages-cd-3/)
[GitVersion Documentation](http://gitversion.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

While using only one branch. Is it still possible auto incrementing version number and putting proper descriptors such as CI, "release". If it is possible a good blog post or step by step tutorial would be very helpful.

Also, if you know an alternative tool or how to implement such a versioning on TFS. It would be helpful too.

Answer (score 1):

To version control in one branch, we can only check in the changes with meaningful comments.

To increment version number in TFS, you can create a build/release definition. Then set the build/release name format as needed. It's applied to both TFVC and Git.

For the build/release name format, you can use a combination of tokens, variables, and underscore characters to set much more useful names that are meaningful to your team.

eg:

```
CI_Beta_$(TeamProject)_$(BuildDefinitionName)_$(SourceBranchName)_$(Date:yyyyMMdd)$(Rev:.r)
```

Just add the Copy File step to save the versioned source to any server or UNC path.

Please see [Build definition options](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/define/options) for details.

[image]

Comment: I would like to use descriptors like “CI”, “beta”, and “release”. The documents covers most of the things except descriptors. How should I manage when beta artifact become a release? Do you have any opinion?

Comment: @melih.tt  If you use the build definition, you just need to change the build number format, you can type any descriptors as the format, just as showed in above screenshot  eg, when beta artifact become a release, you can change the format as Release_$(Date:yyyyMMdd)$(Rev:.r). You can also create a CD Release to manage it. See https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/overview